# Can I write "this closely"?

Tags: adverbs

Did I use the adverb correctly in the following sentence?

> Marriage is one of almost global human institutions, and no institution has affected human beings this closely.

Is it correct to use "this close" in the sentence above?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but *closely* is a strange adverb to use with *affected*.

Comment: What @Andrew said. I can't really get my head around what it would mean to be ***closely** affected* - but according to Google Books, 49 things [were closely affected](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22were+closely+affected%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22were+closely+affected%22&tbm=bks&start=40) in print, so I guess it must mean *something*.

Comment: This question should not have been closed as proofreading, because the asker did clearly identify a specific source of concern in the text.

Comment: I'd say it's unacceptable: 'this -ly' needs a specified comparator. _Marriage is a near-universal human institution, and no other institution has affected human beings so significantly._ is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adv. appears grammatically correct in a technical sense, I suppose.

**OR.....no institution has affected human beings **so closely**.

=> Use of **'this**" is not flawed since it can be used to identify a specific person or thing **close at hand** or being indicated or experienced.

Comment: “Adj.”? You mean adverb? I’m not sure I understand your last sentence. Are you implying that there is some kind of connection between the fact that _this_ has near-deixis and the fact that the following adverb is _closely_?

Comment: Corrected, thx..I did consider deictic usage of "this" but I'am not convinced. Discourse-deixis ?

Comment: But i don't see any justification for the deictic usage of "this".
What type of deixis, if any.

@Mou, you provided the literal meaning of ...["this"]